# Wrong labelling of contours with ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 12.3.1 or later**

---

Consider this example:

```
dat = Table[Re[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]], {x, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}, {y, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}];
```

Now pay special attention to the labelling of contours.

Here everything looks good:

```
ListContourPlot[dat, Contours -> {1., 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5}, ContourLabels -> All]
```

[image]

But look!

```
ListContourPlot[dat, Contours -> Range[1, 0.5, -0.1], ContourLabels -> All]
```

[image]

The labelling of contours is now wrong: it is inverted.  The largest one gets the smallest label.

As far as I can tell, the two `ListContourPlot` commands are completely equivalent.  One has a `Range`, the second one has what the `Range` would evaluate to.

```
Range[1, 0.5, -0.1]
(* {1., 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5} *)
```

`ListContourPlot` is not `HoldAll`.

```
Attributes[ListContourPlot]
(* {Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

I must be missing something obvious, but it's late here and I'm tired and I cannot see what.  I'm using M10.4 on OS X.

**Update:**  I solved the mystery: the difference between `Range[1, 0.5, -0.1]` and `{1., 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5}` is that the former is a packed array.  It seems this is just a plain old bug...

Comment: Given your discovery, a workaround -- other than avoiding use of `Range` -- would be `ListContourPlot[dat, Contours -> (# & /@ Range[1, 0.5, -0.1]), ContourLabels -> All]`

Comment: @BobHanlon. Turns out the incredibly silly-looking `List@@Range[1, 0.5, -0.1]` fixes it too.

Comment: You should add bug Tag to the question.

Comment: @Algohi I think it's better if you do that yourself.  The idea is that it should be someone else than the original poster who adds it.  I don't want to show a bad example.

Answer (score 14):

The reason for the difference between the outputs is that `Range[1,0.5,-0.1]` is a packed array while `{1., 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5}` is not.

If the `Contours` specification is a packed array, the output will be incorrect.

`` Developer`FromPackedArray@Range[...] `` can be used as a workaround.

---

When being an option of `Interpolation`, `ListInterpolation`, `FunctionInterpolation`, using packed array as the option value of `InterpolationOrder` also causes problem:

```
f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}, InterpolationOrder ->{3}]
(* Works as expected *)
f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}, InterpolationOrder -> Developer`ToPackedArray@{3}]
```

[image]

Comment: that is just bizarre.

Comment: Also, if the contours are in ascending order, it works fine.